# Cannot open Excel file

Tags: ruby, excel

I've tried using:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

require 'win32ole'

xl = WIN32OLE.new('excel.application')

wrkbook= xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Excel\\workbook1.xls")

wrksheet = wrkbook.Worksheets(2)

wrksheet.Visible=1
```

And Also Tried

```
wrksheet.Visible=True
```

Script is Executing Without Error, but it's not opening the Excel file. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I think what you're missing is xl.Visible=True (the worksheet is visible by default, but the application is hidden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get data from Excel, use a gem like [roo](http://rubygems.org/gems/roo).

Comment: I have Downloaded That Gem roo and how to install/include in ruby